# Manipulating a Variable from a .foreach loop in Windbg

Tags: windbg

I am trying to enumerate in a Windbg script a list of objects and perform an operation on.

So i get the Directory objects then i do a foreach on each object in that directory.

```
.foreach /pS 19 /ps 1 (Address {!object @$t7}) {!object Address}
```

The problem is that "Address" is not always an address token. I need to skip non-numeric tokens. I can't do that using /ps , without skipping some valid addresses and screwing up the tokens.

I tries something like 
    .if ($spat(Address, "*-*")) != 1
    { 
    }

but that did not work.

Can i not perform operations on the Variable "Address" before actually passing it to the OutCommand ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tries something like `.if ($spat(Address, "-")) != 1 { }`

This should work, but your syntax is slightly incorrect. You will need something like this:

```
.if ( $spat( "Address","[0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f]" ) )
{
    some code;
};
```

This will match addresses. See the String Wildcard Syntax page in windbg help for more details on matching.

Answer (score 0):

try to use python with windbg ( https://pykd.codeplex.com )
this is a sample working with windows object manager:
https://pykd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#branch/0.2.x/samples/km/drvobj.py
It's very simple!!!